# Passing multiple columns to Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am analyzing a pollution data set and have data in this format

```
City    Month  SO2 level
SF      Jan    8
SF      Jan    9
SF      Jan    8.2
....
SF      Feb    8.3
....
NYC     Jan    9
```

I want to find the mean of the SO2 level in different cities *per month* . How can I use python to do that for me? I have tried using pandas groupby method as it seems the most appropriate option, but I failed to do so.

Comment: Are you looking for df.groupby(['City', 'Month'])['SO2 level'].mean()

Comment: That worked. thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help:)